# Drifting a car in bge

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to make a rally game.How to make a python or logic bricks (if it is possible) that can make a car drift when I turn left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(blend example file)
   ==>https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yny39dZCLL8pv886YI0fmaarocPItcwh<==

in this example you can drift(go sideways) get drift score(depending on drift speed) very simple actually. Feel free to use this example .